# insert multiple columns between two columns in a data frame and an automated way to fill them

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, cluster-analysis

I have a data frame called df.
My data frame has three columns. code, name and cluster
cluster column includes numbers from 1 to 10, such that each number indicates what cluster that row belongs to.
I want to add 10 columns between columns: name and cluster columns and name them p.1 to p.10.
and fill these columns such that, if the row value in cluster column is 1, then corresponding cell in P.1 column gets 1 and the rest of the row gets zero. if  the row value in cluster column is 2, then corresponding cell in P.2 column gets 1 and the rest of the row gets zero. and so on.

I know I must add my work here, which is something I ve been doing so far. but honesty for this one, I  do not know how to even begin to do this in an automated way. for each single row, I can do it but since I have about 500 rows it does not make sense.

I would really appreciate helping me with this.

EDIT:
thank you for introducing dummy_cols() function.

Now I m wondering, is there any similar direct function to fill the columns not with 1 but with other values.

Comment: I m not sure what it means. I try giving positive feedback by clicking the top arrow ,  but it does accept it saying I do not have enough reputation. ;(

Comment: Have a look at dummy_cols: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastDummies/vignettes/making-dummy-variables.html

Comment: @akrun,,,, got it! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(fastDummies)

df <- data.frame(Cluster = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE))
df <- dummy_cols(df, select_columns = "Cluster")
```